# R Markdown File Is Not Giving Me the Output

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have the following code:

````
```{r}
library(sqldf)
library(caret)
library(ROCR)

turnover = read.csv("active_20120630.csv")
```
````

When I run the code in R Studio, everything is fine. But when I clicked `Knit HTML`, I got the following errors after the last line `turnover = read.csv("active_20120630")`:

```
## Warning: cannot open file 'active_20120630.csv': No such file or directory
## Error: cannot open the connection
```

Why I can run them in the console but not in the HTML output?

Thanks

Comment: Did you save your markdown file in the same directory as your project file? Did you try an absolute path to the file?

Comment: I used the absolute directory `turnover = read.csv("C:/Users/pma/Dropbox/Clorox_Desktop/Perri/R/Data/active_20120630.csv")` and it worked. However I saved the markdown file in a folder called "markdown" and this folder is inside the working directory. Is there a shorter way to specify the file path rather than staring from `C:`?

Comment: You can always try to specify a relative path from where your markdown file is instead.

Comment: To go up one directory, you can try `"..\active_20120630.csv"` perhaps (not tested--just guessing). :-)

Comment: I suggest you accept one of the answers below. @damienfrancois's answer essentially sums up my comments, but Mike's is also a good suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error `No such file or directory` means it cannot find the file. Given that the filename is relative to the current directory, you most probably are in one directory when you try it with R Studio and in another when you try it with knit.

Try using an absolute path for the file such as (Linux):

```
turnover = read.csv("/home/user/active_20120630.csv")
```

or (Windows)

```
turnover = read.csv("C:/My Project/active_20120630.csv")
```

Make sure to replace the path in the example above with the actual one.

Alternatively, you can modify your global settings in knit as @Mike.Gahan suggests.

Comment: I used the absolute path and it worked. See my comments to Ananda Mahto above - is there a shorter way to specify the path given the markdown file is within the working directory, but under a separate folder? Thanks!

Comment: Use `../` in the path to refer to the parent directory.

Comment: that second one wont work in r... but paths like c:/my project/ will work in windows, so why not just use forward slashes regardless of os

Comment: @damienfrancois, for the windows version, it should be forward slash not backward slash, like what rawr mentioned. I was not able to edit your answer. Suggest that you update your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add some stuff to your global settings.:

````
```{r global options, include=FALSE}
#set root directory
opts_knit$set(root.dir="~/your/working/directory")
```
````